# perl reading file to array with varying row lengths, "use of uninitialized value"

Tags: arrays, perl, text, row, pdb

First post so please forgive if I formatted poorly. This is more of an annoying output problem that prevents easy scanning for true errors than anything. In short I have to break every row of a large file into individual characters, but the length of the row isn't the same so towards the end I get a blast of "use of uninitialized values". The script works fine but again it's hard to see the actual output I need to see what is going on and which lines it chooses not to use. Details and relevant script below.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

Maybe if I didn't use these my problem would go away but I'd like to keep it together.

I have a script that is made to manipulate a pdb file which need exact column number of values. My script is in perl and takes in 10-50K files. It first breaks every line into individual characters (stored in array @line) and stores a specific number of characters into an array called @column. It then checks the first string of 6 characters and throws out any that don't match 1 of three specific strings. Also it changes column 22 into the letter "A". Finally storing everything into another file. The lines range from 3 characters to 80 so for each array element that is NULL from the file being blank throws this error when not all 80 characters are present. I saw a post with similar problem but they were doing a csv file which I can't use as explained. I can't just detect for spaces wither because as you can see in the file example below fields bleed into each other so it has to be column specific.

read-in section:

```
while (my $row = <FH>) {
chomp $row;
$row =~ s/^\s+//;
@line = split(//, $row);
$column[0] = join ('', @line[0..5]);
$column[1] = join ('', @line[6..10]);
$column[2] = join ('', @line[11..15]);
$column[3] = join ('', $line[16]);
$column[4] = join ('', @line[17..19]);
$column[5] = join ('', $line[20]);
$column[6] = join ('', $line[21]);   # Chain ID
$column[7] = join ('', @line[22..25]);  #residue number
$column[8] = join ('', $line[26]);
$column[9] = join ('', @line[27..37]);
$column[10] = join ('', @line[38..45]);
$column[11] = join ('', @line[46..53]);
$column[12] = join ('', @line[54..59]);
$column[13] = join ('', @line[60..65]);
$column[14] = join ('', @line[66..75]);
$column[15] = join ('', @line[76..77]);
```

this error is present for about 60+ lines for short rows:

```
no match
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./change_chain_ID_to_A.pl line 35, <FH> line 33828.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./change_chain_ID_to_A.pl line 35, <FH> line 33828.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./change_chain_ID_to_A.pl line 35, <FH> line 33828.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./change_chain_ID_to_A.pl line 36, <FH> line 33828.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./change_chain_ID_to_A.pl line 36, <FH> line 33828.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at ./change_chain_ID_to_A.pl line 36, <FH> line 33828.
```

etc...etc

example lines from input file

```
HETATM33701 CA   CA  I2111      20.810  32.443 -53.618  1.00  0.00          Ca
HETATM33702 CA   CA  I2112      -7.146  39.054 -51.559  1.00  0.00          Ca
CONECT 3502 3501 4093
CONECT 4093 3502 4092
CONECT119241192312515
CONECT125151192412514
CONECT203462034520937
```

Comment: It looks like you have chosen wrong approach to the task. Your code expects that each and every line should be 78 characters long. Sample of data provided indicates that lines are not constant length and your program can not extract data which does not exist. From your description it is not obvious what you try to achieve. A quick lookup for `HETATM` leads to believe that you try to work with [proteins sequences](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/sect9.html). Please edit your question and provide a description of data source and what final result should look.

Comment: Perhaps [CPAN](https://www.cpan.org/) has a module to handle such data and you try to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: What do you want to do when there are no more elements in `@line`?  Not assign any more columns or assign empty to the remaining ones? In particular, what when there are partial ranges? For example, if the line has 8 characters: (1) what should `$column[1]` get?  (It needs 5 chars but there would be only 2 available.) (2) what about the rest of the intended columns?

Comment: @PolarBear for example, [parsepdb](https://comp.chem.nottingham.ac.uk/parsepdb/)

Comment: It is slightly overkill to split a string into characters, and then use array slices to join them back together. If you want to do that, you can just use [`substr`.](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr). In this case, more logic is required, though, since your string length varies, and you are trying to use characters which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is provided for educational purpose only with an accent on parsing fixed length structured data records.

OP did not provide enough information to make a suggestion to direct OP in right direction.

The correct approach is to use CPAN genetics module which was designed specifically for such job/purpose.

Demo code demonstrates usage of [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack) function to extract data structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;
use YAML;

my($data,$model,$index);

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    next if /^ENDMDL|^\s+\z/;
    my $item;
    $index = 0                  if /^MODEL/;
    $model = parse_model($_)    if /^MODEL/;
    $item  = parse_atom($_)     if /^ATOM/;
    $item  = parse_hetatm($_)   if /^HETATM/;
    $item  = parse_ter($_)      if /^TER/;
    $data->{$model->{serial}}[$index++] = $item if defined $item;
}

#say Dumper($data);
say Dump($data);

sub parse_model {
    my $line = shift;
    my $model;
    
    my @fields = qw/record_name serial/;
    
    $model->@{@fields} = unpack('a6x4a4');
    defined($model->{$_}) && $model->{$_} =~ s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @fields;
    
    return $model;
}

sub parse_atom {
    my $line = shift;
    my $atom;

    my @fields = qw/record_name serial name altLoc resName chainID resSeq iCode x y z occupancy tempFactor element charge/;
    
    $atom->@{@fields} = unpack('a6a5xa4aa4aa8a8a8a8a6a6x11a2a2',$line);
    defined($atom->{$_}) && $atom->{$_} =~ s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @fields;
    
    return $atom;
}

sub parse_hetatm {
    my $line = shift;
    my $hetatm;

    my @fields = qw/record_name serial name altLoc resName chainID resSeq iCode x y z occupancy tempFactor element charge/;

    $hetatm->@{@fields} = unpack('a6a5xa4aa4aa8a8a8a8a6a6x11a2a2',$line);
    defined($hetatm->{$_}) && $hetatm->{$_} =~ s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @fields;
    
    return $hetatm;
}

sub parse_ter {
    my $line = shift;
    my $ter;
    
    my @fields = qw/record_name serial resName chainID resSeq iCode/;
    
    $ter->@{@fields} = unpack('a6a5x6a3aa4a',$line);
    defined($ter->{$_}) && $ter->{$_} =~ s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @fields;
    
    return $ter;
}

__DATA__
         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
MODEL        1
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   1      11.104   6.134  -6.504  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   1      11.639   6.071  -5.147  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM 3835 FE   HEM A   1      17.140   3.115  15.066  1.00 14.14          FE
HETATM 8238  S   SO4 A2001      10.885 -15.746 -14.404  1.00 47.84           S  
HETATM 8239  O1  SO4 A2001      11.191 -14.833 -15.531  1.00 50.12           O  
HETATM 8240  O2  SO4 A2001       9.576 -16.338 -14.706  1.00 48.55           O  
HETATM 8241  O3  SO4 A2001      11.995 -16.703 -14.431  1.00 49.88           O  
HETATM 8242  O4  SO4 A2001      10.932 -15.073 -13.100  1.00 49.91           O
ATOM    293 1HG  GLU A   18    -14.861  -4.847   0.361  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM    294 2HG  GLU A   18    -13.518  -3.769   0.084  1.00  0.00           H
TER     295      GLU A   18                                           
ENDMDL                                                              
MODEL        2                                                       
ATOM    296  N   ALA  A   1     10.883   6.779  -6.464  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM    297  CA  ALA  A   1     11.451   6.531  -5.142  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM 3835 FE   HEM A   1      17.140   3.115  15.066  1.00 14.14          FE
HETATM 8238  S   SO4 A2001      10.885 -15.746 -14.404  1.00 47.84           S  
HETATM 8239  O1  SO4 A2001      11.191 -14.833 -15.531  1.00 50.12           O  
HETATM 8240  O2  SO4 A2001       9.576 -16.338 -14.706  1.00 48.55           O  
HETATM 8241  O3  SO4 A2001      11.995 -16.703 -14.431  1.00 49.88           O  
HETATM 8242  O4  SO4 A2001      10.932 -15.073 -13.100  1.00 49.91           O
ATOM    588 1HG  GLU A   18    -13.363  -4.163  -2.372  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM    589 2HG  GLU A   18    -12.634  -3.023  -3.475  1.00  0.00           H
TER     590      GLU A   18                                          
ENDMDL
```